# Can Django give same functionality as my current Drupal sites?

Tags: django, drupal

Im building website in Drupal, which have:
**Feed aggregator**
-Aggregate feeds and mapping to categories, tags
**Ping**
-Ping new contents to search engines, Ping-o-matic, etc.
**Workflow**
-When contents is viewed, publish to front page
-When contents published to front page, send ping to search engines, Ping-o-matic, etc.
**Import HTML static files from old website**
-Import to specific category, to specific content types

Can Django doing this?

Answer (score 1):

**Feed aggregator: Feedjack**
`http://www.feedjack.org/`

**Ping All Search Engines**
`http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1308/`

**GoFlow workflow engine**
`http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/GoFlow`

**Import HTML static files from old website?**
Im not sure about this in django.